# How to reduce the size of the citation(like [1]) generated by \cite{1} tag in latex

Tags: latex, reduction, citations

Wikipedia neatly superscripts n reduces the size of all the citations. Is there a way to get it in latex.

Comment: There's an SE just for TeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look into [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) which improves citation usage compared to vanilla LaTeX, and allows much easier customization. To make citations appear in superscript <sup>[1]</sup> you would add the `super` option; numbers in square brackets are activated by `numbers` and `square`, respectively, i.e. add

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, super]{natbib}
```

in the preamble of your document. I also like to use commas to separate entries (`comma`) and activate automatic compression of adjacent references<sup>[1-12,42]</sup> (`sort&compress`).